# What to do if reliability test result is not up to 0.7?

Tags: spss, ordinal-data, reliability, scales, categorical-data

I have gathered 257 questionnaires with 43 variables. The requirement for my research department need me to make the reliability test up to 0.7 or else it is consider not reliable. But mine is 0.5. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Crossvalidated. Several things to ask: First, I am assuming you mean Cronbach's alpha.  Second, what is alpha now?  Third, please post the results of the test as part of your question.  In particular, there should be data on the result of removing each variable. Fourth, what exactly have you tried and what happened?

Comment: hi.. thankyou for ur response ..
yes, i mean the cronbach's alpha.. the result i get is 0.634 and N of the items is 25..i have used all my question that using likert's scale to test the reliability which is my section C question.. my friend suggest me to use negatively worded to change the value of some negative question. but it suprisingly decrease the cronbach's alpha result to 0.3 something... i try to reduce my questionnaire but i don't think it will help me..

Answer (score 3):

In your comment to me you noted that alpha is now 0.634, so it is at least close.

First, note that any cutoff value is arbitrary. That probably won't help you in this particular case, but it's good to keep in mind.

Second, look at the responses to each question. If any have very little variation, they are candidates for removal.

Next, I suggest looking at what happens to alpha if each question is removed. If it jumps up by a huge amount for some question, then look at that question and see what is going on with it.

Fourth, look at the correlation matrix of the items. If there are any that are large and negative, look at that question and try to figure out what is going on. It might be worded in the wrong direction.

Finally, do an exploratory factor analysis and see if there are actually more than one latent variables in your data.

Comment: orait.. but it is okay if we removed some of the question??.. as for me i have removed 4 question makes my total question become 21..

I apologize very much because I was still new to this spss world.. and do i need to combine the ordinal and scale(likert's scale) measure when test for reliability..